# Using wxPython Menus, ID: What does it mean and Which should I use for X?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxPython app I'm working on.  I'm working on the menu and menu bars.

So far here is the code I have:

```
class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=    (350,200))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()

        menu = wx.Menu()
        m_exit = menu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "&Exit\tAlt-X", 
            "Close window and exit program.")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnClose, m_exit)

        menu = wx.Menu()
        m_about = menu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About", "Information about this     program")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, m_about)
        menuBar.Append(menu, "&Help")

        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        m_text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Hello World!")
        m_text.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        m_text.SetSize(m_text.GetBestSize())
        box.Add(m_text, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        m_close = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_CLOSE, "Close")
        m_close.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)
        box.Add(m_close, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        panel.SetSizer(box)
        panel.Layout()

    def OnClose(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 
            "Do you really want to close this application?",
            "Confirm Exit", wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            self.Destroy()

    def OnAbout(self, event):
        dlg = AboutBox()
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
```

I wanted to add New, Open, Save, SaveAs to the File menu, add an Actions menu and within it put Action1, Action2 (temp names).  My only questions are these:

First of all, in the statement `m_exit = menu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, etc...` what does the wx.ID_EXIT mean?  And where can I get a list of possible ID's?  I'm not sure what I would set for New, Open, Save, SaveAs, etc.  I will make OnNew, OnOpen, etc functions, but I'm not sure of what the ID should be.  I heard about custom ID's but I need an example because I can't seem to find anything that makes sense to me about them.  I see you use them in Append() but not Bind().  Why id this?  What exactly is the reason for passing it to Append()?  like in m_exit (see below),  I use wx.ID_EXIT, but then in Bind I never mentioned it again I just mention wx.EVT_MENU, the function to be executed and the name of the menu.Append().   How do these items interact??

EDIT:

I tried this code:

```
    menu = wx.Menu()
    ID_FILE_NEW = wx.NewId()
    m_new = menu.Append(wx.ID_FILE_NEW, "&New\tCtrl+N", "txt")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnNew, m_new)     

    ID_FILE_OPEN  = wx.NewId()
    m_open = menu.Append(wx.ID_FILE_OPEN, "&Open\tCtrl+O", "txt")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, m_open)

    ID_FILE_SAVE = wx.NewId()
    m_save = menu.Append(wx.ID_FILE_SAVE, "&Save\tCtrl+S", "txt")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, m_save)

    ID_FILE_SAVE_AS = wx.NewId()
    m_save_as = menu.Append(wx.FILE_SAVE_AS, "&SaveAs", "txt")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSaveAs, m_save_as)

    m_exit = menu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "&Exit\tCtrl+X", 
        "Close window and exit program.")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnClose, m_exit)

    menuBar.Append(menu, "&File")
```

It didn't work, the application opened and then closed instantly, when I remove everything but m_close, it works again.  Obviously my wx.NewId() variables aren't working? What am I doing wrong in either creating my own wx.NewId's or setting up the menubar for more menus and menuitems.  I know I'm doing at least one of these things wrong.  Can anyone help me figure out what it is and suggest the best way to accomplish the goal?

EDIT Cont'd:

I have two classes that derive from wx.Dialog.  Here is the code:

```
class AboutBox(wx.Dialog):
def __init__(self):
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, -1, "About",
        style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE|wx.THICK_FRAME|wx.RESIZE_BORDER|
            wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
    hwin = HtmlWindow(self, -1, size=(400,200))
    vers = {}
    vers["python"] = sys.version.split()[0]
    vers["wxpy"] = wx.VERSION_STRING
    hwin.SetPage(aboutText % vers)
    btn = hwin.FindWindowById(wx.ID_OK)
    irep = hwin.GetInternalRepresentation()
    hwin.SetSize((irep.GetWidth() + 25, irep.GetHeight() + 10))
    self.SetClientSize(hwin.GetSize())
    self.CentreOnParent(wx.BOTH)
    self.SetFocus()

class VersionBox(wx.Dialog):
def __init__(self):
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, -1, "Version",
        style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE|wx.THICK_FRAME|wx.RESIZE_BORDER|
            wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
    hwin = HtmlWindow(self, -1, size=(400, 200))
    vers = {}
    vers["python"] = sys.version.split()[0]
    vers["wxpy"] = wx.VERSION_STRING
    hwin.SetPage(versionText % vers)
    btn = hwin.FindWindowById(wx.ID_OK)
    irep = hwin.GetInternalRepresentation()
    hwin.SetSize((irep.GetWidth() + 25, irep.GetHeight() + 10))
    self.SetClientSize(hwin.GetSize())
    self.CentreOnParent(wx.BOTH)
    self.SetFocus()
```

Where it cals hwin.FindWindowById(wx.ID_OK) I don't see how it's finding the correct window.  For example the AboutBox displays the about window but in it's menu.Append it uses wx.ID_ABOUT, but wx.ID_OK works fine.  I am now trying to implement VersionBox.  But I'm not sure what to change that to.   ID_ABOUT like in the menu.Append()?  Or something else.

If it's not obvious by now I don't understand these ID's, when to use them, which ones to use, and how they interact with GetWindowById() please clarify...

I try to follow the pattern I see in examples and tutorials, but when I add new menuitems to a menu it never seems to work.  I don't get an error message but the program opens and closes right away.  I'm following this code: http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPython%20by%20Example  But I can't seem to get any menuitems to work other than what they've already added.  Any ideas ?

Thanks A Million, sorry for putting up with me but I'm having some trouble.  Even answering some of my questions or some clarification would help big time in my understanding of how wxPython works.

FINAL EDIT:

I got it working with version, by using wx.ID_ABOUT like the OnAbout() method.  Seems that if I add other OnX() methods, even if they aren't bound to anything messes the program up, why would that be?

Thanks a ton, your help  has guided me the right way, if anybody can supply some small examples it would help a lot.  If not, thanks anyway I'm finally on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. wx.ID_EXIT is an integer ID that wx has reserved an knows the meaning of ... there are others such as `wx.Button(self,wx.ID_OK)` notice I do not need to pass a string label (with wx.ID_EXIT it should automagically trigger the close event as well (unless you catch the menu event and short circuit it), these work differently depending on the context that they are used in

   you could get a list of all the wx.ID_XXX with `[n for n in dir(wx) if n.startswith("ID_")]`
2. wx.EVT_MENU is the command event generated by any menu selection (including accelerator table hotkeys) , you can see what it has by using `dir(event)` inside the function handler ... but I think it only has the default commandevent fields.
3. `APP_EXIT` is a string the programmer wrote somewhere something like `APP_EXIT=_("&Exit")` ... this is a common practice to use all capital letters for constants (it also helps simplify localization).
4. wxPython will try to parse whatever hotkey combination you give it so +/- probably does not matter(although this is not documented well so I dont know ... you could do some trial and error and find out pretty easy)

   ```
   menu = wx.Menu()
   ID_PRG_NFO = wx.NewId()
   m_about = menu.Append(ID_PRG_NFO, "Program &Info\tAlt-I", "Information about this     program")
   ```

for a OPEN menu option you could do

```
    m_open = menu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN,"&Open\tAlt-O)
```

ok here is the list of special ID's in wxPython2.8

```
>>> import wx
>>> [n for n in dir(wx) if n.startswith("ID_")]
['ID_ABORT', 'ID_ABOUT', 'ID_ADD', 'ID_ANY', 'ID_APPLY', 'ID_BACKWARD', 'ID_BOLD
', 'ID_CANCEL', 'ID_CLEAR', 'ID_CLOSE', 'ID_CLOSE_ALL', 'ID_CONTEXT_HELP', 'ID_C
OPY', 'ID_CUT', 'ID_DEFAULT', 'ID_DELETE', 'ID_DOWN', 'ID_DUPLICATE', 'ID_EDIT',
 'ID_EXIT', 'ID_FILE', 'ID_FILE1', 'ID_FILE2', 'ID_FILE3', 'ID_FILE4', 'ID_FILE5
', 'ID_FILE6', 'ID_FILE7', 'ID_FILE8', 'ID_FILE9', 'ID_FIND', 'ID_FORWARD', 'ID_
HELP', 'ID_HELP_COMMANDS', 'ID_HELP_CONTENTS', 'ID_HELP_CONTEXT', 'ID_HELP_INDEX
', 'ID_HELP_PROCEDURES', 'ID_HELP_SEARCH', 'ID_HIGHEST', 'ID_HOME', 'ID_IGNORE',
 'ID_INDENT', 'ID_INDEX', 'ID_ITALIC', 'ID_JUSTIFY_CENTER', 'ID_JUSTIFY_FILL', '
ID_JUSTIFY_LEFT', 'ID_JUSTIFY_RIGHT', 'ID_LOWEST', 'ID_MORE', 'ID_NEW', 'ID_NO',
 'ID_NONE', 'ID_NOTOALL', 'ID_OK', 'ID_OPEN', 'ID_PAGE_SETUP', 'ID_PASTE', 'ID_P
REFERENCES', 'ID_PREVIEW', 'ID_PREVIEW_CLOSE', 'ID_PREVIEW_FIRST', 'ID_PREVIEW_G
OTO', 'ID_PREVIEW_LAST', 'ID_PREVIEW_NEXT', 'ID_PREVIEW_PREVIOUS', 'ID_PREVIEW_P
RINT', 'ID_PREVIEW_ZOOM', 'ID_PRINT', 'ID_PRINT_SETUP', 'ID_PROPERTIES', 'ID_RED
O', 'ID_REFRESH', 'ID_REMOVE', 'ID_REPLACE', 'ID_REPLACE_ALL', 'ID_RESET', 'ID_R
ETRY', 'ID_REVERT', 'ID_REVERT_TO_SAVED', 'ID_SAVE', 'ID_SAVEAS', 'ID_SELECTALL'
, 'ID_SEPARATOR', 'ID_SETUP', 'ID_STATIC', 'ID_STOP', 'ID_UNDELETE', 'ID_UNDERLI
NE', 'ID_UNDO', 'ID_UNINDENT', 'ID_UP', 'ID_VIEW_DETAILS', 'ID_VIEW_LARGEICONS',
 'ID_VIEW_LIST', 'ID_VIEW_SMALLICONS', 'ID_VIEW_SORTDATE', 'ID_VIEW_SORTNAME', '
ID_VIEW_SORTSIZE', 'ID_VIEW_SORTTYPE', 'ID_YES', 'ID_YESTOALL', 'ID_ZOOM_100', '
ID_ZOOM_FIT', 'ID_ZOOM_IN', 'ID_ZOOM_OUT']
>>>
```

Comment: So if I wanted to write menu items Open, New, Save, SaveAs, and some other custom actions, how do I know which integer ID to use?  What if none of the built in ones satisfy my needs, how can I make a custom one?  Can you provide a short example of doing so?

Comment: Where can I find the definitions for things like ID_PRG_INFO and such, and is there a way to make custom ID's?  I still am having  trouble understanding the ID's.  If you are already binding it to a method why do you need the ID?  For example, my example code uses ID_ABOUT instead of ID_PRG_INFO.  How do I know which to use when it isn't obvious?

Comment: that is a new customid look at the line above ...`ID_PRG_NFO = wx.NewId()` if you should use an ID it should be obvious if it is not obvious that you should use a builtin wx.ID_XXX , then you should just use a custom ID ... the builtin ID's have a little tiny bit of magic built into them (depending on context (ie a button or a menu or a dialog return)

Comment: I see.  So what is the point of the ID's, since I'm binding to the correct method why do I need an ID? Also what parameters does NewId() take?  For example In the example its ID_ABOUT rather than ID_PRG_INFO.  What is placed inside of those NewId()'s ?  And for something more complex like save, open. new, etc.  How would you write an ID?  I could just create a custom ne with wx.NewId() but there has to be more to it. Otherwise what is the point of the ID's?

Comment: NewID() generates a new id that is guaranteed to not already be in use as an ID ... it accepts no parameters ... all an ID is , is a unique integer... thats it ... the special builtin wx.ID_XXXX are handled in a unique way by the wx or OS framework depending on the context the ID is used in

Comment: Thanks I'm sort of understanding, can you provide a small example of these ID's that could possibly help me understand which I should use and when/how to make my own?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78843/discussion-between-shenk-and-joran-beasley).

Comment: You said for m_open I could do `m_open = menu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN,"&Open\tAlt-O)`  What does ID_OPEN mean exactly? When I go to bind it I never  use ID_OPEN so what is it even needed for? Sorry I can't seem to wrap my brain around this. 

And for EVT_MENU, what is the difference between EVT_MENU, MENU_RANGE, MENU_OPEN,  MENU_CLOSE, MENU_HIGHLIGHT, MENU_HIGHLIGHT_ALL, etc?  It says t hey are events emitted by MenuItem class, but for a Menubar will I always use EVT_MENU?   Unless I want specific behavior for menu open/close/highlight an item?  Is this correct?

 Any more help is much appreciated.

Comment: ID_OPEN is __just a number__ specifically  it is the integer 5000 ... if you use ID_OPEN in a button for example you dont need to put a label `wx.Button(self,wx.ID_OPEN)` will automatically create a keyboard shortcut of ctrl+o and write the label="&Open" on the button ... because wx knows something about these ID's ... but they are just numbers

Comment: So if I use ID_OPEN I don't need to do "&Open" in the binding?  and it'll automatically create ctrl+o?  What if I wanted to change the shortcut, then I'd just have to do it manually? See EDIT

Comment: Check my first and second edits for my more specific questions regarding ID's and their interactions.  Thanks

Comment: this question (and answer) has already become too long to be helpful to more people than just you... please put your edits in as a separate question that can stand on its own ...

Comment: here is a list of special ids and their integer values http://wiki.wxpython.org/SpecialIDs , you should also download the wxDemo and Docs executable

Comment: Sure thing, although theyu somewhat pertain.  I will try to reword and then divide into more questions if I can't reword it well

Comment: Big help thanks, but what about custom ID's.  Why create them and how?  I see examples but when I try them it doesn't work.  In the examples they just do ID_XXX = wx.NewId()

Comment: thats all you do ... what do you mean by it doesnt work?

Comment: Okay but  say I do ID_XXX =  wx.NewId()   is there anything else I have to do to make it work?  What is the point of ID's?  If there isn't anything else to relate them to a method or anything.  Seems to me you just use them in  Append() but I don't see what effect it has.  In Bind() you don't reference them at all.

Comment: Basically, how do  Append() and Bind() work together with the ID's?  A short explanation should do it.  Thanks

Comment: you can `btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnButton,id=MY_CUSTOM_ID)` and that handler would only be triggered by the button with that ID ... the point is everything needs some kind of unique identifier ... that is what an ID is ... wx magically knows how to handle some of these magic numbers on its own

Comment: So say we are using a menu rather than a button.  the wx.ID_ABOUT in m_close = Append(...) corresponds to the Bind() 3rd paremeter m_close?

Is this at all correct?

Still don't see what wx.EVT_MENU does in the Bind() method.  Are the ID's added to EVT_MENU?

Comment: m_close is a MenuItem.  MenuItems have a GetId()(in fact all most every wx.element has a GetId() method), bind takes an optional 3rd argument to use as the source .. or an optional 4th argument which is the element ID ... EVERYTHING in wx has ID .... its not just menu's it is EVERY SINGLE ELEMENT